# onClick conditional executing on load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a php-based authorization setup that loads authorization level into a JS variable, and I'd like to disable onclick events based on the authlevel.

I've written/borrowed the following partial that works fine for executing arbitrary functions with their parameters (from other excellent stackoverflow posts). I've tested it with functions passing parameters and it works great.

```
function checkauth(authlevel, reqauthlevel, callback, message) {
    // Handle custom message or lack thereof
    message = (typeof message === "undefined") ? "You do not have authorization for this action" : message;

    if (authlevel >= reqauthlevel) {
        callback()
    }
    else {
        alert(message)
    }
}
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        return func.apply(this, allArguments);
    };
}
```

When I call it to handle a button event, however, I get the auth message on page load using the code below. Is there a better way to handle events to selectively ignore them? I know I can use php to just not create the buttons, or js to delete them or produce them selectively, but I'd like to have them there as a demo for UI experience without the action results. TIA - c

```
$(function(){
    $('#spdownbutton').click(checkauth(authlevel, 2, function(){
        var selectedchannelname=document.getElementById("selectchannel").value
         $.ajax({
            url: "/wsgiupdatecontrol",
            type: "post",
            datatype:"json",
            data
                {'action':'spchange','subaction':'incdown','database':controldatabase,'channelname':selectedchannelname},
            success: function(response){
                setTimeout(UpdateChannelData,updatetimeout)
            }
         });
     }, stdmessage));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#spdownbutton').click(function(){
        checkauth(authlevel, 2, function(){
        var selectedchannelname=document.getElementById("selectchannel").value
         $.ajax({
            url: "/wsgiupdatecontrol",
            type: "post",
            datatype:"json",
            data
                {'action':'spchange','subaction':'incdown','database':controldatabase,'channelname':selectedchannelname},
            success: function(response){
                setTimeout(UpdateChannelData,updatetimeout)
            }
         });
     }, stdmessage);
    });
}
```

Comment: Beauty. Thanks for the quick response. I noted that the partial is unnecessary in this case as well, so I should not have included it.